# drop down menu with position absolute , not working in overflow scroll ,How do I fix it?

Tags: css, dropdown, overflow, css-position

Because of the overflow, the menu opens inside the box and it must be a box with overflow. Do you have a solution for this, friends?

[image]

Comment: it was better if you added a piece of code.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Comment: .box {
    height: 525px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.9rem;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 1rem #9ea8b23d;
    max-height: 13.3rem;
}

Comment: This is only caused by overflow. And because I want the box to have a fixed size and scroll from the inside, I can't remove the overflow. Considering that the drop down position is absolute, but it still opens inside.
I tried all the ways, but unfortunately I didn't have an answer :((

Comment: can you create a codesandbox or codepen for your code? I can't get what you mean by your CSS code and image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a higher `z-index` to the dropdown.
`.dropdown { z-index: 1000; }`

Comment: This is only caused by overflow. And because I want the box to have a fixed size and scroll from the inside, I can't remove the overflow. Considering that the drop down position is absolute, but it still opens inside.
I tried all the ways, but unfortunately I didn't have an answer :((